# Unicode HttpResponse from xmlDocument

Tags: xml, encoding, httpresponse

I have an XmlDocument that I wish to encode as Unicode and then write it to Response.OutputStream.

```
XmlWriterSettings xWriterSettings = new XmlWriterSettings();
xWriterSettings.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;
XmlWriter xWriter = null;
XmlWriter.Create(xWriter, xWriterSettings);
_xResp.Save(xWriter);
```

I have so far managed to encode and write it to an XmlWriter.
Any suggestions I can do this faster/better?

Comment: Your code can't possibly work. Please confirm that this is the real code.

Comment: John,
The code compiles but I haven't run it yet.

Comment: You'll get an `ArgumentNullException` as soon as you run it.

Comment: Please advise me how to unicode a HttpResponse.
I just tried this and I am not sure if this worked.
Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;
_xResp.Save(Response.OutputStream);

Comment: What do you mean "how to unicode an HttpResponse"? "Unicode" is a noun, not a verb. What is `_xResp`? Do you realize that you never change `xWriter` from its value of `null`?

Comment: John, the code I wrote above was to show what I was trying so that I can advised accordingly.
When I say unicode a response, it means I want to set the encoding as Unicode. _xResp is a XmlDocument which I wish to encode and set to Response.

Comment: Try just `_xResp.Save(Response.Output)`. If your output is Unicode encoded, then this will do the right thing. If it isn't, then I don't know why you want to output the XML in a different encoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering on John's behalf:
Try just _xResp.Save(Response.Output). If your output is Unicode encoded, then this will do the right thing. If it isn't, then I don't know why you want to output the XML in a different encoding.

```
Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;
_xResp.Save(Response.OutputStream);
```